# Keycloak admin client - javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy, keycloak

Im using the Keycloak admin client (version 4.5.0.Final) and am trying to do some simple queries such as looking up a user. The client code is running in a plugin module in another java server, not standalone.  The code looks like this:

```
    ...
    try {
        Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance(URL, REALM, USER, PWD, CLIENT_ID);

        UserRepresentation kcuser = kc.realm(REALM).users().get(USER).toRepresentation();

        trace(String.format("Got user: %s",  kcuser.toString()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        trace("Error authenticating: " + e);
    }
    ...
```

It creates the kc instance successfully, but barfs when trying to look up the user. 
This is the error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:40)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:146)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:121)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:394)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:666)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:631)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:509)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:310)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:439)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:148)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy362.grantToken(Unknown Source)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:89)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:69)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:64)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:587)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:436)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:148)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy372.toRepresentation(Unknown Source)
...
```

My pom has the latest dependencies and classpath seems ok, any ideas why this is not working?

```
<properties>
    <keycloak.version>4.5.0.Final</keycloak.version>
    <resteasy.version>3.6.1.Final</resteasy.version>

</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>                   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>                               
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610464/java-keycloak-library-fails-in-jar-file

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that during the instantiation of a new `Keycloak` instance, resteasy is checking [here](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/3.9/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/RegisterBuiltin.java#L60) for the available providers with the help of the current thread. In version `3.9.1.Final` which is currently used by the last `keycloak-admin-client` so far (version `11.0.0`).

In my specific case we are using `keycloak-admin-client` in combination with `graphql-java` and `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` for our data loaders. Which implies that in some cases, without further configuration, the current thread is not an instance of `Thread` but actually `ForkJoinWorkerThread`. Which apparently breaks the retrieval of the providers.

I am still a beginner to java so I would be glad if someone could explain why the [`registerProviders` method](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/3.9/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/RegisterBuiltin.java#L60) does not work with a `ForkJoinWorkerThread`.

I learned on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/be-aware-of-forkjoinpoolcommonpool) is that JVM sizes the `commonPool` to two threads when you have more than 2 CPUs available. So I tried and noticed that my app works with 2 CPUs, but I have the same error (RESTEASY003215) with 3 CPUs.

My current "workaround" is to to use `CompletableFuture.completedStage` when loading data using the `keycloak-admin-client`.